# How to run TensorFlow in Google App Engine Flexible Enviroment?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, tensorflow

Before I asked why GAE can't find TensorFlow lib here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40241846/why-googleappengine-gives-me-importerror-no-module-named-tensorflow

And `Dmytro Sadovnychyi` told me that GAE can't run TensorFlow, but GAE flexible can.

So I created my project in USA zone and trying to deploy my simple project:

```
import webapp2
import tensorflow as tf

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
        sess = tf.Session()
        self.response.write(sess.run(hello))
        a = tf.constant(10)
        b = tf.constant(32)
        self.response.write(sess.run(a + b))
        #self.response.write('asd');


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

witn `vm: true` in yaml.

This is yaml:

```
application: tstmchnlrn
version: 1
runtime: python27
vm: true
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

Deploy successes, but I getting Server Internal Error when visiting my app at `appspot` and console still shows me `ImportError: No module named tensorflow`.

What I need to do to make TensorFlow based app to run in `flexible enviroment`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like the dependency didn't get pushed to the instance.

Create a `requirements.txt` file and [list your dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-python-libraries#declaring_and_managing_dependencies), including Tensor Flow there.

Comment: so, I created requirements.txt file and placed in together with my `yaml` and `py` files. It's content is just a link: `https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.11.0rc1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl`. After deploying this project and retesting I still got same error about TensorFlow module not found. Do I need to do something else special to make VM install TensorFlow? I deploying project through PyCharm.

Comment: The Storage link is a 404. Should that be publicly accessible?

Comment: I don't know... but this command works fine from console: `Metafalica@DESKTOP-MC1D431:~$ pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.11.0rc1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
Downloading/unpacking https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.11.0rc1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
  Downloading tensorflow-0.11.0rc1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl (39.8MB):  97%  39.0MB`

Answer (score 4):

To help anyone else, I am posting my hello world tensor flow code for google app engine flexible environment using **Python 3** (I know that original question was asked for python 2.7). Also note that webapp2 is not yet compatible with python 3, so I am using Flask.

Complete code is

**requirements.txt**

```
Flask==0.12.2
gunicorn==19.7.1
tensorflow==1.3.0
```

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: python
threadsafe: yes
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
```

**main.py**

```
# Copyright 2015 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# [START app]
import logging
import platform
import tensorflow as tf

from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello():
    """Return a friendly HTTP greeting."""
    # Simple hello world using TensorFlow

    # Create a Constant op
    # The op is added as a node to the default graph.
    #
    # The value returned by the constructor represents the output
    # of the Constant op.
    hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')

    # Start tf session
    sess = tf.Session()

    return sess.run(hello).decode()+' Python '+ platform.python_version()


@app.errorhandler(500)
def server_error(e):
    logging.exception('An error occurred during a request.')
    return """
    An internal error occurred: <pre>{}</pre>
    See logs for full stacktrace.
    """.format(e), 500


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # This is used when running locally. Gunicorn is used to run the
    # application on Google App Engine. See entrypoint in app.yaml.
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
# [END app]
```

This same code is also posted on github [here](https://github.com/armujahid/appengine-tensorflow-python3)