# `TFRecord` dumping from Google BigQuery to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I would like to write an ETL Transform job, to

- query elements from BigQuery
- apply some transformation on them
- serialise into the `TFRecords` format
- dump the `.tfrecords` in a Cloud Storage bucket

The solution can possibly use Google Cloud products.

I tried using App Engine cron jobs, along with Google Cloud Python APIs but App Engine cannot be deployed with tensorflow (which is necessary for `TFRecords` serialisation).

**Any recommendation on how this could be done smoothly?**

Comment: You could write your pipeline in python then run the whole thing on a Google Cloud virtual machine?

Answer (score 1):

AppEngine standard can not run TensorFlow but AppEngine flexible can.
See example here [How to run TensorFlow in Google App Engine Flexible Enviroment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40310602/how-to-run-tensorflow-in-google-app-engine-flexible-enviroment)